# d3 contour Observable to Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, observable, contour

I am converting the d3 contour example https://observablehq.com/@d3/volcano-contours?collection=@d3/d3-contour to vanilla js for a stand alone application. I am new to observable and JS.

```
    <html>
      <head>
       <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
       <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-contour.v2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-hsv.v0.1.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container"></div>

    <script>
    function vChart(container){
    
      const data = FileAttachment("volcano.json").json();       
      const height = data.height;
      const width = data.width;
      const contours = d3.contours().size([width, height]);
      const path = d3.geoPath();        
            
    function interpolateTerrain() {
      const i0 = d3.interpolateHsvLong(d3.hsv(120, 1, 0.65), d3.hsv(60, 1, 0.90));
      const i1 = d3.interpolateHsvLong(d3.hsv(60, 1, 0.90), d3.hsv(0, 0, 0.95));
      return t => t < 0.5 ? i0(t * 2) : i1((t - 0.5) * 2);
    }

    const color = d3.scaleSequential(interpolateTerrain).domain(d3.extent(data.values)).nice();
    const thresholds = color.ticks(20);

    const wide = Generators.observe(notify => {
      let wide;
      function resized() {
        let w = innerWidth > 640;
        if (w !== wide) notify(wide = w);
      }
      resized();
      addEventListener("resize", resized);
      return () => removeEventListener("resize", resized);
    })

      const svg = d3.select(container).append('svg')
          .attr("viewBox", wide ? [0, 0, width, height] : [0, 0, height, width])
          .style("display", "block")
          .style("margin", "0 -14px")
          .style("width", "calc(100% + 28px)")
          .style("height", "auto");

      const g = svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform", wide ? null : `
            rotate(90 ${width/2},${height/2})
            translate(${(width - height) / 2},${(width - height) / 2})
          `)
          .attr("stroke", "white")
          .attr("stroke-width", 0.03);
      
      for (const threshold of thresholds) {
        g.append("path")
            .attr("d", path(contours.contour(data.values, threshold)))
            .attr("fill", color(threshold));

        yield svg.node();
      }

    }       

    vChart('.container')
          
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

This results in two errors

1. Uncaught ReferenceError: Fileattachment is not defined
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: Generators is not defined

I am not able to recreate the generator function, Fileattachment function I guess it is related to observable.